# mobile input feedback design pattern

Tags: mobile, design-patterns, ios, email, verification

I am creating email verification in IOS and want to assist the user with verifying they have entered the correct email address before sending confirmation.

Some app use an instant input feedback with javascript to quickly inform the user his password is invalid, misspelled - www.ui-patterns.com/collections/input-feedback/entry/573, or sometimes use tooltips to just informs them what the field is.

I am looking for a way to prompt the user during or after user enters his email information and taps done other than alertbox popup. Any design patterns for tooltip in this use case?

Answer (score 1):

I've had some design discussions on this and had come up with a few options using a combination of some of them:

1. Change the background colour of the cell. Optionally change the text colour of the form label.
2. Add an accessory view like a '?' icon to the end of the cell, tapping on the icon can present an alert/tooltip.
3. Add a footer or header label to table section to advise what is considered a valid response. (Only applicable if the whole section should be reviewed.)
4. Keep the 'Done'/'Submit' button disabled until a valid response is entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colour of the input text or the down colour of the input field border to provide feedback for the user. See an example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms) (scroll to "Invalid inputs" or "Validation states").

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Maybe I don't understand the answer, but I am not looking for a state change, after the user taps done on the keypad or keyboard. I think that may indicate the user something is wrong. I just want to inform the user to check if they're password is correct with possibly a better pattern than the alert popup (if there is one).

Comment: You don't have to change the state after tapping. You can change the state after you have validated the password. Or whenever else you want. As I said, I gave a link of an example, not a link that you have to copy exactly the same thing. The idea is that instead of a tooltip you can change the state at any moment you think it's most useful to your users. That depends on the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do NOT want inline validation for whatever reason.  So to answer your question, you could avoid an alert by doing something like this.  Show an error message inline at the top of the page describing the error, then highlight the specific input fields that are invalid.  Optimally, you can also put text next to the input field describing the error in more detail.

[image]

With that said, I think a better UX will be to show errors inline, if it's technically feasible.  This way the user can focus on each input field, as it's entered, and correcting the error is much more seamless, than doing it after the entire form has been filled out and submitted.

Neither of these methods are built into iOS, you will need to do some custom programming.

[image]